# Need Multiple WITH statements in SQL UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a SQL UDF that I need to define both WITH SCHEMABINDING and WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER on.  I've tried a number of combinations including listing the WITH keyword twice, trying various methods of concatenation or operators, etc, and haven't had a lot of luck.

Can anybody help me with how to define multiple WITH statements in a single UDF

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Func_PullFolderIdsForUser](@companyId [int], @userId [int])
    RETURNS @folders TABLE (
        [FolderID] [int] NULL,
    ) WITH SCHEMABINDING 
    AS 
    BEGIN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comma delimit them. e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Func_PullFolderIdsForUser](@companyId [INT], @userId [INT])
    RETURNS @folders TABLE (
        [FolderID] [INT] NULL
    ) WITH SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS SELF
    AS 
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @folders VALUES(1)
    RETURN
    END
```

Comment: Wow that easy.. thanks.. not sure why I couldn't come up with that.